Sorting using Oracle SQL Hierarchical Join path without inflating row count
I've written a query with an Oracle SQL hierarchical join that I think is a bit inefficient. I'm hoping someone can point me to a more efficient means of achieving what I want.
Background on the problem:

I need to correctly sort a set of records (uniquely identified by segment_id) we are receiving from a third-party database. The records are ordered by record_time, but due to truncation of the timestamp, some records will have the exact same record_time. We cannot guarantee that the records will be sorted into the desired order when we retrieve them, but we need to sort records within the same timestamp into the correct order.
Thankfully, we have a 'neighbors' table that tells us the expected connection between two segments. For example, if I have two segments 'A' and '1' at the same record_time, I can look at the reprex_neighbors_table to see that where segment_id = 'A', the next_segment_id is '1', so '1' must follow 'A'.
A few other challenges are:

Some segments will have multiple parents and children in the neighbors table, not all of which will manifest in the segment data. I have one example of multiple children in the example below.
Because we have many, many segments, it isn't practical to start at the original part of the hierarchy and work all the way down; we only want to use hierarchical queries to sort within a given record_time. The reprex below doesn't illustrate the workarounds for that, but you get the idea.
Sometimes we get more than one record in successive time stamps, so you can't look back to the previous timestamp to immediately see what the desired antecedent is. I would like to avoid loops or even more extensive subqueries in my code for the sake of performance, but if that's the recommended approach, let me know.



To summarize, here's an example of the data:
This is the reprex_segments_table (for convenience, cast r_time is shown)



ORIGINAL_ORDER
DESIRED_ORDER
SEGMENT_ID
RECORD_TIME
r_time




1
1
25-52-21
1-Apr-24
7:57:18


2
2
45-85-44
1-Apr-24
7:57:26


5
3
51-1-97
1-Apr-24
8:04:12


4
4
81-24-87
1-Apr-24
8:04:12


3
5
18-11-88
1-Apr-24
8:04:12


7
6
79-60-16
1-Apr-24
8:04:54


6
7
12-80-48
1-Apr-24
8:04:54


8
8
11-58-36
1-Apr-24
8:05:12


9
9
90-49-72
1-Apr-24
8:05:36



This is the reprex_neighbors_table. Notably, the last record here in the reprex is a superfluous child to one record; in practice each record can have up to 3 parents and/or 3 children!



SEGMENT_ID
NEXT_SEGMENT_ID




25-52-21
45-85-44


45-85-44
51-1-97


51-1-97
81-24-87


81-24-87
18-11-88


18-11-88
79-60-16


79-60-16
12-80-48


12-80-48
11-58-36


11-58-36
90-49-72


81-24-87
69-67-78



Here's a bit of code to create the example tables.
CREATE TABLE reprex_segment_data (
    original_order int,
    desired_order int,
    segment_id VARCHAR(20),
    record_time DATE
);

CREATE TABLE reprex_neighbors_table (
    segment_id VARCHAR(20),
    next_segment_id VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT ALL INTO reprex_segment_data (
    original_order,
    desired_order,
    segment_id,
    record_time
) VALUES (
    1,
    1,
    '25-52-21',
    TO_DATE('7:57:18', 'HH24:MI:SS')
) INTO reprex_segment_data (
    original_order,
    desired_order,
    segment_id,
    record_time
) VALUES (
    2,
    2,
    '45-85-44',
    TO_DATE('7:57:26', 'HH24:MI:SS')
) INTO reprex_segment_data (
    original_order,
    desired_order,
    segment_id,
    record_time
) VALUES (
    5,
    3,
    '51-1-97',
    TO_DATE('8:04:12', 'HH24:MI:SS')
) INTO reprex_segment_data (
    original_order,
    desired_order,
    segment_id,
    record_time
) VALUES (
    4,
    4,
    '81-24-87',
    TO_DATE('8:04:12', 'HH24:MI:SS')
) INTO reprex_segment_data (
    original_order,
    desired_order,
    segment_id,
    record_time
) VALUES (
    3,
    5,
    '18-11-88',
    TO_DATE('8:04:12', 'HH24:MI:SS')
) INTO reprex_segment_data (
    original_order,
    desired_order,
    segment_id,
    record_time
) VALUES (
    7,
    6,
    '79-60-16',
    TO_DATE('8:04:54', 'HH24:MI:SS')
) INTO reprex_segment_data (
    original_order,
    desired_order,
    segment_id,
    record_time
) VALUES (
    6,
    7,
    '12-80-48',
    TO_DATE('8:04:54', 'HH24:MI:SS')
) INTO reprex_segment_data (
    original_order,
    desired_order,
    segment_id,
    record_time
) VALUES (
    8,
    8,
    '11-58-36',
    TO_DATE('8:05:12', 'HH24:MI:SS')
) INTO reprex_segment_data (
    original_order,
    desired_order,
    segment_id,
    record_time
) VALUES (
    9,
    9,
    '90-49-72',
    TO_DATE('8:05:36', 'HH24:MI:SS')
)
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        dual;

INSERT ALL INTO reprex_neighbors_table (
    segment_id,
    next_segment_id
) VALUES (
    '25-52-21',
    '45-85-44'
) INTO reprex_neighbors_table (
    segment_id,
    next_segment_id
) VALUES (
    '45-85-44',
    '51-1-97'
) INTO reprex_neighbors_table (
    segment_id,
    next_segment_id
) VALUES (
    '51-1-97',
    '81-24-87'
) INTO reprex_neighbors_table (
    segment_id,
    next_segment_id
) VALUES (
    '81-24-87',
    '18-11-88'
) INTO reprex_neighbors_table (
    segment_id,
    next_segment_id
) VALUES (
    '18-11-88',
    '79-60-16'
) INTO reprex_neighbors_table (
    segment_id,
    next_segment_id
) VALUES (
    '79-60-16',
    '12-80-48'
) INTO reprex_neighbors_table (
    segment_id,
    next_segment_id
) VALUES (
    '12-80-48',
    '11-58-36'
) INTO reprex_neighbors_table (
    segment_id,
    next_segment_id
) VALUES (
    '11-58-36',
    '90-49-72'
) INTO reprex_neighbors_table (
    segment_id,
    next_segment_id
) VALUES (
    '81-24-87',
    '69-67-78'
)
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        dual;

Here's my proposed solution. The logic is to work 'backwards' almost by making the current record the 'next' segment and looking up the prior segment. I also work record_time into the connect by statement to essentially partition the join. The resulting path is longest for the record that should be at the end within a record_time partition and shortest for the one that should be at the beginning, which is my desired outcome.

WITH add_neigh AS (
    SELECT
        reprex_segment_data.original_order,
        reprex_segment_data.desired_order,
        reprex_segment_data.segment_id,
        reprex_segment_data.record_time,
        to_char(reprex_segment_data.record_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS r_time,
        reprex_neighbors_table.segment_id                      AS parent_segment_id
    FROM
        reprex_segment_data
        LEFT JOIN reprex_neighbors_table
 --here, we try to remove children that aren't relevant to our path in some fashion
 --if there's a better way to handle this (especially with many more records)
 --would appreciate advice.
        ON reprex_neighbors_table.next_segment_id IN (
            SELECT
                reprex_neighbors_table.next_segment_id
            FROM
                reprex_neighbors_table
            WHERE
                reprex_neighbors_table.next_segment_id = reprex_segment_data.segment_id
        )
), add_neigh_path AS (
    SELECT
        add_neigh.original_order,
        add_neigh.desired_order,
        add_neigh.segment_id,
        add_neigh.record_time,
        add_neigh.r_time,
        add_neigh.parent_segment_id,
        level,
        connect_by_iscycle                                                                               AS is_cycle,
        sys_connect_by_path(add_neigh.parent_segment_id, '/')
        || '/'
        || add_neigh.segment_id                                                                          AS path,
 --for reasons i don't entirely understand, multiple paths are generated for each record with various levels of
 --depth; we want to keep the longest one
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY add_neigh.segment_id, add_neigh.record_time ORDER BY level DESC) AS rn_highest_level
    FROM
        add_neigh
    CONNECT BY
 -- PRIOR child -> parent relationship
        NOCYCLE PRIOR add_neigh.segment_id = add_neigh.parent_segment_id
 -- this is what partitions the hierarchy
        AND PRIOR add_neigh.record_time = add_neigh.record_time
    ORDER BY
        add_neigh.original_order
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    add_neigh_path
WHERE
    rn_highest_level = 1
ORDER BY
    record_time,
    path

Which produces:



ORIGINAL_ORDER
DESIRED_ORDER
SEGMENT_ID
RECORD_TIME
R_TIME
PARENT_SEGMENT_ID
LEVEL
IS_CYCLE
PATH
RN_HIGHEST_LEVEL




1
1
25-52-21
1-Apr-24
7:57:18

1
0
//25-52-21
1


2
2
45-85-44
1-Apr-24
7:57:26
25-52-21
1
0
/25-52-21/45-85-44
1


5
3
51-1-97
1-Apr-24
8:04:12
45-85-44
1
0
/45-85-44/51-1-97
1


4
4
81-24-87
1-Apr-24
8:04:12
51-1-97
2
0
/45-85-44/51-1-97/81-24-87
1


3
5
18-11-88
1-Apr-24
8:04:12
81-24-87
3
0
/45-85-44/51-1-97/81-24-87/18-11-88
1


7
6
79-60-16
1-Apr-24
8:04:54
18-11-88
1
0
/18-11-88/79-60-16
1


6
7
12-80-48
1-Apr-24
8:04:54
79-60-16
2
0
/18-11-88/79-60-16/12-80-48
1


8
8
11-58-36
1-Apr-24
8:05:12
12-80-48
1
0
/12-80-48/11-58-36
1


9
9
90-49-72
1-Apr-24
8:05:36
11-58-36
1
0
/11-58-36/90-49-72
1



Here are some challenges:

Joining the neighbors table has the potential to inflate record counts. With the subquery in my example it's not so bad, but in the full dataset this is not ideal.
The add_neigh_path CTE table has many levels shown, and I don't understand why. I have to sort by path length and then filter on RN_HIGHEST_LEVEL. The example below shows what that table looks like. This isn't so bad in the reprex data but can become really big in my full table.




ORIGINAL_ORDER
DESIRED_ORDER
SEGMENT_ID
RECORD_TIME
R_TIME
PARENT_SEGMENT_ID
LEVEL
IS_CYCLE
PATH
RN_HIGHEST_LEVEL




1
1
25-52-21
1-Apr-24
7:57:18

1
0
//25-52-21
1


2
2
45-85-44
1-Apr-24
7:57:26
25-52-21
1
0
/25-52-21/45-85-44
1


5
3
51-1-97
1-Apr-24
8:04:12
45-85-44
1
0
/45-85-44/51-1-97
1


4
4
81-24-87
1-Apr-24
8:04:12
51-1-97
2
0
/45-85-44/51-1-97/81-24-87
1


3
5
18-11-88
1-Apr-24
8:04:12
81-24-87
3
0
/45-85-44/51-1-97/81-24-87/18-11-88
1


4
4
81-24-87
1-Apr-24
8:04:12
51-1-97
1
0
/51-1-97/81-24-87
2


3
5
18-11-88
1-Apr-24
8:04:12
81-24-87
2
0
/51-1-97/81-24-87/18-11-88
2


3
5
18-11-88
1-Apr-24
8:04:12
81-24-87
1
0
/81-24-87/18-11-88
3


7
6
79-60-16
1-Apr-24
8:04:54
18-11-88
1
0
/18-11-88/79-60-16
1


6
7
12-80-48
1-Apr-24
8:04:54
79-60-16
2
0
/18-11-88/79-60-16/12-80-48
1


6
7
12-80-48
1-Apr-24
8:04:54
79-60-16
1
0
/79-60-16/12-80-48
2


8
8
11-58-36
1-Apr-24
8:05:12
12-80-48
1
0
/12-80-48/11-58-36
1


9
9
90-49-72
1-Apr-24
8:05:36
11-58-36
1
0
/11-58-36/90-49-72
1



So, in short, is there a way to achieve my desired sort:

with less row count explosion/filtering?
without need for a subquery?

Many thanks!

I suggest reading [mre] as very long questions rarely get good engagement

I hear ya--10 records was about as short as I could make it, admittedly showing the tables in question makes it look bulkier

Focus in on an example that demonstrates the core behaviour you need, that you're having trouble with. Don't take a subset of the actual full scale problem. Cut out absolutely everything that you can when producing the representative example.

I believe I already did so, thank you.

Done on a phone so comment rather than answer ; https://dbfiddle.uk/ntvErE0S

Or, if a segment can be mapped to more than one preceding segment; https://dbfiddle.uk/X3wEP-eA

Brilliant! Had briefly considered the iterative approach but hadn't attempted it, very impressed how quickly you whipped that up. I think your approach is actually a bit more suited to the underlying data even if it doesn't use the hierarchical query, happy to accept as answer if you want to submit it as an answer. Thank you for bearing with my longish post, hah

You can use a hierarchical query to generate an ordering of the neighbours table and then join the data table to that ordering:
WITH order_ids (segment_id, order_id) AS (
  SELECT segment_id,
         MIN(depth + type)
  FROM   (
    SELECT segment_id,
           next_segment_id,
           LEVEL AS depth
    FROM   reprex_neighbors_table
    START WITH segment_id NOT IN (SELECT next_segment_id FROM reprex_neighbors_table)
    CONNECT BY PRIOR next_segment_id = segment_id
    ORDER SIBLINGS BY segment_id
  )
  UNPIVOT (segment_id FOR type IN (segment_id AS 0, next_segment_id AS 1))
  WHERE  type = 1
  OR     depth = 1
  GROUP BY segment_id
)
SELECT d.*
FROM   reprex_segment_data d
       INNER JOIN order_ids o
       ON d.segment_id = o.segment_id
ORDER BY
       d.record_time,
       o.order_id

Which, for the sample data, outputs:



ORIGINAL_ORDER
DESIRED_ORDER
SEGMENT_ID
RECORD_TIME




1
1
25-52-21
2024-04-01 07:57:18


2
2
45-85-44
2024-04-01 07:57:26


5
3
51-1-97
2024-04-01 08:04:12


4
4
81-24-87
2024-04-01 08:04:12


3
5
18-11-88
2024-04-01 08:04:12


7
6
79-60-16
2024-04-01 08:04:54


6
7
12-80-48
2024-04-01 08:04:54


8
8
11-58-36
2024-04-01 08:05:12


9
9
90-49-72
2024-04-01 08:05:36



Which is in the desired order.
fiddle

Very clever! Had not considered trying to assign a sort on the neighbors table first, and the combination of type + depth was very inspired. I will mark this as the answer for now--I think the MatBailie approach may actually work better for my underlying data given the complicated segment relationships, so I may mark his comment as an answer if he decides to submit as later, but I think this is a great use of hierarchical joins, learned a lot from this
